# Data lookup using Coldfusion, Ajax, and CFC

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I'm using a string instead of an integer as a key to do a data lookup on a table using ColdFusion and Ajax. My test is not returning any values and I'm completely stomped. I tried to convert the ajax value to a string.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#init").blur(function() {
            alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
            var initVal = JSON.stringify({'$(this).val()'});
            if(initVal != "") {
                $.get("testrun.cfc?method=getuser&init=initVal", function(res) {
                    $("#team").val=res;
                }, "JSON");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type='text' name='init' id='init' /><br>
<input type='text' name='team' id='team'/>
```

ColdFusion component

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cffunction name="getuser" access="remote" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="init" type="string" required="yes">

      <cfquery name="getUser" datasource="#DSN#">
       SELECT       team
         FROM       users
        WHERE       init = <cfqueryparam value = "#arguments.init#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      </cfquery>

    <cfreturn getUser.TEAM /> 
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Does the query return any records if you run it outside of ColdFusion?

Comment: @Dan yes it returns a value, but the value doesn't display in the TEAM form field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the *string* "initval" in your Ajax call.

In other words, jQuery will not magically turn

```
"testrun.cfc?method=getuser&init=initVal"
```

into

```
"testrun.cfc?method=getuser&init=whateverYouEnteredInTheTextfield"
```

Pass the *value* of the variable instead, and leave the URL parameter building to jQuery completely:

```
$("#init").blur(function() {
    var initval = $.trim(this.value);
    if (!initval) return;

    $.get("testrun.cfc" {
        method: "getuser",
        init: initval
    }).done(function (res) {
        $("#team").val(res);
    });
});
```

It helps to open the network tab in your browser's developer tools and look at the Ajax requests as they are happening.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and I've implemented your method. But I'm still not getting data back from the database.

Comment: Hard to say. I don't know your database and I can't see what you're doing. Open the URL `testrun.cfc?method=getuser&init=SomeTeamId` manually in the browser. What does it show? Work on your CFC until that shows expected result for `SomeTeamId`. After that, the jQuery side of things will likely start to work, too.

Comment: I opened the URL as suggested and got the value from the database to display. The issue is the value is not displaying in the form field.

Comment: What does the network tab of the browser developer tools show?

Comment: I got an Uncaught SyntaxError on 'if !(initval) return;'

Comment: Oh snap, typo on my end.

Comment: what was the typo?

Comment: there was a "," missing after "testrun.cfc" also, but it's working now. I'm getting a return value in the TEAM form field. The only issue is it's displaying like: '<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>BME</string></data></wddxPacket>' I only want to display 'BME'.

Comment: That's a different question. You are getting a WDDX-encoded response, because that's the default in ColdFusion. Switch to JSON response encoding (it's in the docs) and you should be good.

Comment: Got it! I set the returnformat to plain in the cffunction tag. @Tomalak thanks for all your help. As you can tell I was completely lost. I appreciate the help. :-)

Comment: I'm sure you learned a great deal, and that's the whole point. :)